# Chrome not looking right while driven by Codeception

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, codeception

Chrome is not rendering correctly while been driven by Codeception using selenium. The whole chrome instance then will look like this.

If chrome is startet the usual way it works fine.

[image: Chrome driven by selenium]

What can I do to get Chrome to look right while using Codeception?

Comment: [Don't do this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361474/should-we-display-a-warning-when-users-include-images/361481#361481)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved running Chrome with the `--disable-gpu` argument.